# I am trying to to write 2 functions together in T-SQL to get the character string that I need to create a ContractID value

Tags: sql-server, string, function, t-sql, nested

I can't seem to get the `Replace` & `Left` functions to work together to remove the dash `'-'` without errors and I need both to achieve what I am trying to do.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Subscriber_Id, REPLACE(LEFT(Subscriber_Id, 3), Subscriber_Id, '-') AS ContractID
FROM 
    EDW_ODS.dbo.ODS_LABCORP_LABS
WHERE 
    ContractId IS NULL
```

[image]

I also tried this but get a new column and when I try nesting them together I just errors.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Subscriber_Id, 
    LEFT(Subscriber_ID, 3), REPLACE(Subscriber_ID, '-', '') AS ContractID
FROM 
    EDW_ODS.dbo.ODS_LABCORP_LABS
WHERE 
    ContractId IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: *"I just errors."* And what is that error?

Comment: Are you *sure* the character is a hyphen (`-`) and not some similar character?

Comment: It would save you some time if you write: I have subscriber ID = 47-1191437, and i want to create column that just returns 47, and another column that returns 1191437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just get the stuff after the first "-" you can do something like:

```sql
select stuff(Subscriber_Id, 1, 3, '') AS ContractIDVersion1
, RIGHT(Subscriber_Id, LEN(Subscriber_Id) - 3) AS ContractIDWithRight
, REPLACE(Subscriber_id, LEFT(Subscriber_Id, 3), '') AS ContractIDByReplace
, CASE WHEN CharIndex('-', Subscriber_id) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Subscriber_id, CharIndex('-', Subscriber_id) + 1, LEN(Subscriber_id)) ELSE Subscriber_id END AS ContractIDByCharIndex
FROM 
    EDW_ODS.dbo.ODS_LABCORP_LABS
WHERE 
    ContractId IS NULL
```